# How can I make my reg exp less greedy?

Tags: regex

I'm trying select a small porting of the XML below but my reg exp doesn't work as expected.

My reg exp

```
<w:p [^<>]*><w:r><w:t>\[end participant\]<\/w:t><\/w:r><\/w:p>
```

It should match

```
<w:p w:rsidRDefault="009C141F" w:rsidP="006003BD">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:after="240" />
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:t>[end participant]</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

But it matches up to the first w:p tag.

Here is the complete XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">
  <w:body>
    <w:p w:rsidRDefault="001660DB" w:rsidP="001660DB">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Titre1" />
        <w:spacing w:before="0" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Salut</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidRDefault="001660DB" w:rsidP="001660DB">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Titre2" />
        <w:spacing w:before="0" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>Hello les gens &amp;àè!</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidRDefault="00F87349" />
    <w:p w:rsidRDefault="009C141F">
      <w:r>
        <w:t>[start participant]</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidRDefault="009C141F" w:rsidP="006003BD">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Titre1" />
        <w:spacing w:before="0" w:after="240" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t xml:space="preserve">Mr #NOM# #PRENOM#</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:p w:rsidRDefault="009C141F" w:rsidP="006003BD">
      <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:after="240" />
      </w:pPr>
      <w:r>
        <w:t>[end participant]</w:t>
      </w:r>
    </w:p>
    <w:sectPr w:rsidSect="00425138">
      <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" />
      <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1417" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1417" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
      <w:cols w:space="708" />
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
    </w:sectPr>
  </w:body>
</w:document>
```

thanks

Comment: The problem you're having is a perfect example of why you shouldn't try to parse XML with a regex.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions to parse template tags in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878055/regular-expressions-to-parse-template-tags-in-xml)

Comment: Unfortunately this is OOXML and doesn't parse with PHP Xml parser...

Comment: I guess the OOXML you're trying to match is not with "pretty print", ie. no whitespace as in your example? If it does have whitespaces, than you're missing the line breaks in the expression...

Comment: Yes I pretty printed for the example here but It's not in the original file. I think I need to replace .* with something like .* but not w:p

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the tag for `spacing`:

```
<w:p [^<>]*><w:pPr><w:spacing [^<>]*/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t>\[end participant\]<\/w:t><\/w:r><\/w:p>
```

Comment: The thing is that It could vary. I need the w:p node around the [end participant] string no matter what's inside.